# no architecture to compile for

Tags: ios, architecture, build, frameworks

So I am trying to beta test my first app and I believe one of the first steps is to hit PRODUCT/ARCHIVE.

Background... the app works on the simulator, and when I connect my phone via usb.

So when I hit archive, it said my third party framework was not found.
So I've been reading around for days trying to fix this.

I've been trying to edit the architecture build settings and not sure what I'm doing.  I tried deleting everything in the build valid architectures because thats what seems to work for some people.

Now I can't even build the project.

desperately in need of help as I have no idea what I'm doing to make this project work.

[image]

so I just added armv7.  Not sure if I even did it right, but now I get a new error.

first picture is how I added armv7

[image]

second picture is my NEW error message

[image]

Comment: U need to add required architectures. Like ARM7,ARM7S...

Comment: I tried adding armv7, see picture above for the new error I originally had when I started this... thanks so much for looking at this

Comment: In order to ship to the AppStore, you'll need to have an arm64 slice in your app. This includes all framework or project dependencies. It sounds to me like one of your dependencies does not support arm64. You will need to remove the dependency or update it to a version that does support arm64.

Comment: I deleted armv7 and added arm64, still doesnt work

Comment: The framework name is NMSSH, sftp client.  The documentation said it supports Xcode5 and arm64 architecture.  Is there a special way I need to build the framework before I drag in into my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added framework by using PODS and everything worked